# Typesetting a bilingual English-Hebrew book with facing pages in each language

Tags: luatex, babel, hebrew

How would one go about setting, say, a bilingual novel with the English translation on the left side of the book binding (the verso) and the original Hebrew text on the right side of the book (the recto), so that the two meet in the middle (at the binding)?

(Not that it particularly matters, but I actually want this for Yiddish, not Hebrew...but all the same as far as the typesetting is concerned. See [this example](http://hebrewbooks.org/43653).)

Comment: some possible help here: [Syncing text on bilingual pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86366/579)

Comment: Do you mean, the middle of the page or the middle of the (2-page) sheet?