# 4 parallel text on 2 pages

Tags: reledpar, parallel, parcolumns, parallel-texts

I know there are packages `parcolumns` and `eledpar`.
With `parcolumns` I can have 4 columns on one page. But this is not what I want.
With `eledpar` I can have 2 parallel columns or parallel text on different pages.

What I want is "Text 1 and Text 2" parallel on even pages and "Text 3 and Text 4" on odd pages, such that both page chunks are also parallel.

Or (maybe this can give same result), can I put `eledpar`'s `\begin{pairs}` inside `\begin{pages}`? How?

Or use a different approach to generate PDFs and then use a PDF tool? How?

```
\documentclass[11pt,asymmetric]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}

 \beginnumbering
  \pstart

     \begin{pairs}
        \begin{Leftside}
        1\lipsum[1]
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
     2  \lipsum[2]
        \end{Rightside}
    \Columns
      \end{pairs}

\pend
             \endnumbering
           \end{Leftside}

            \begin{Rightside}
                 \beginnumbering
                      \pstart
                 \begin{pairs}
                    \begin{Leftside}
                 3  \lipsum[3]
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
     4  \lipsum[4]
            \end{Rightside}
    \Columns
    \end{pairs}

             \pend
        \endnumbering
       \end{Rightside}

           \Pages
    \end{pages}

    \end{document}
```

If I comment columns I have 2 Page parallel text. Using 'numbering' 'pstart'/pend commands inside pairs gives errors/becouse of pages and pairs use same counter?/

example below does almost what i need. original post was here [link][Syncing text on bilingual pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86366/syncing-text-on-bilingual-pages/86750#86750) just used it in 'pages' environment...can tehre be a better solution?

```
    \documentclass[11pt,asymmetric]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{eledmac}
    \usepackage{eledpar}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{parallel,hanging}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    \begin{Parallel}[v]{.47\textwidth}{.47\textwidth}
     \ParallelLText{
        \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}
         --- 3\lipsum[3]
      \end{hangparas}
        }
       \ParallelRText{
         \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}
           --- 7\lipsum[7]
       \end{hangparas}
        }
          \end{Parallel}

     \begin{Parallel}[v]{.47\textwidth}{.47\textwidth}
      \ParallelLText{
      \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}
           --- 2\lipsum[2]
    \end{hangparas}
       }
         \ParallelRText{
      \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}
         --- 8\lipsum[8]
       \end{hangparas}

        }
   \end{Parallel}

       \pend
        \endnumbering
     \end{Leftside}

       \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
       \begin{Parallel}[v]{.47\textwidth}{.47\textwidth}
        \ParallelLText{

      \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}
          --- 2\lipsum[2]
       \end{hangparas}

        }
         \ParallelRText{

      \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}


          --- 8\lipsum[8]
        \end{hangparas}

     }
        \end{Parallel}
    \begin{Parallel}[v]{.47\textwidth}{.47\textwidth}
         \ParallelLText{

       \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}
        --- 2\lipsum[2]
       \end{hangparas}

       }
           \ParallelRText{

     \begin{hangparas}{4mm}{1}
      --- 8\lipsum[8]
     \end{hangparas}

       }
    \end{Parallel}
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

    \Pages
    \end{pages}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This can be solution [link]http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130907/how-do-i-create-6-parallel-texts-aligned-by-paragraph-with-3-texts-on-each-page/131394#131394[link] can reduce it to 4 columns, but how to add paragraph numbering

Comment: Please post a Minimal (non-)Working Example with code people can compile to reproduce the issue. Right now, you are expecting anybody who wants to help not only to do the document set up but also to do the `parcolumns`/`eledpar` set up as well. *Show us* what you mean. For example, have you tried putting `\begin{paris}` inside `\begin{pages}`? If not, why not? If so, what went wrong? (Note that I have no idea what these do so no idea whether this is a good idea or not.)

Comment: MNW and MNW Posted

Comment: eledpar coulnd't help you. It should need a totaly new implementation of the system (I have some idea but no time)