# Placing the English translation next to a foreign language text

Tags: two-column, languages, paracol, parallel

I want to use two columns to place the English translation of a text in a foreign language next to the original text in that foreign language. How can I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the `paracol` package for parallely typeset columns.

Comment: leandris  Where can I find the paracol package?

Answer (score 2):

I use the package `parallel` [CTAN -- parallel](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parallel/). I don't know if there are better solution, but this one fit my requerements.

There are some options to split between left/right pages or columns, and also adding lines between columns.

A simple column division is presented in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage[german, brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

CAPE -- MWE package parallel with bilingual -- single page

\clearpage

Before 1st Parallel with \verb|\textwidth|.

\begin{Parallel}{0.48\textwidth}{0.48\textwidth} %[options]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
    \ParallelLText{ %
        \selectlanguage{brazil}

        Este texto está em alemão.

        left-text 1.1

        \lipsum[1-5]

        left-text 1.2

        \vfill

    }
    \ParallelRText{ %
        \selectlanguage{german}

        Dieser Text ist auf Deutsch.

        right-text 1.1

        \lipsum[1-5]

        right-text 1.2

        \vfill
    }
    \ParallelPar
    \ParallelLText{left-text 2}
    \ParallelRText{right-text 2}
    \ParallelPar

    \renewcommand{\ParallelAtEnd}{text at end of 1st parallel.}
\end{Parallel}

After 1st parallel.

Before 2nd parallel with \verb|\linewidth|.

\begin{Parallel}{0.48\linewidth}{0.48\linewidth} %[options]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
    \ParallelLText{ %
        \selectlanguage{brazil}

        Este texto está em português.

        left-text 3.1 

        \lipsum[1-5]

        left-text 3.2

        \vfill

    }
    \ParallelRText{ %
        \selectlanguage{german}

        Dieser Text ist auf Portugiesisch.

        right-text 3.1

        \lipsum[1-5]

        right-text 3.2

        \vfill
    }
    \ParallelPar
    \ParallelLText{left-text 4}
    \ParallelRText{right-text 4}
    \ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}

After 2nd parallel.

\end{document}
```

Some pieces of the results. Considere adjusting margins to split the text bettter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit**: following Ad van der Ven's comments.

A shorter version with `\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}` and the suggested English and German texts. There are two repetitions of the texts. Check the behaviors (un)commenting lines with `\selectlanguage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Titlepage -- MWE package parallel with bilingual -- single page.

\clearpage

Before 1st Parallel with \verb|\textwidth|.

\begin{Parallel}{0.48\textwidth}{0.48\textwidth} %[options]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \ParallelLText{ %
        \enquote{This text is in German}.

        Besonders auffällig ist der frühere Eintritt der Reifungszeit und damit auch der Geschtechtsreife bei den Mädchen, die den Knaben um 1-2 Jahre vorauseilen. 
    }

    \selectlanguage{ngerman}
    \ParallelRText{ %
        \enquote{Dieser Text ist auf Deutsch}.

        Particularly noticeable is the earlier onset of the maturation period and thus also the maturity level of the girls, who are 1-2 years.
    }
    \ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}

After 1st parallel.

Before 2nd parallel with \verb|\linewidth|.

\begin{Parallel}{0.48\linewidth}{0.48\linewidth} %[options]{\linewidth}{\linewidth}
    % \selectlanguage{english} % No space
    \ParallelLText{ %
        \selectlanguage{english} % With space
        \enquote{This text is in English}.

        Besonders auffällig ist der frühere Eintritt der Reifungszeit und damit auch der Geschtechtsreife bei den Mädchen, die den Knaben um 1-2 Jahre vorauseilen. 
    }

    %\selectlanguage{ngerman} % No space
    \ParallelRText{ %
        \selectlanguage{ngerman} % With space
        \enquote{Dieser Text ist auf Englisch}.

        Particularly noticeable is the earlier onset of the maturation period and thus also the maturity level of the girls, who are 1-2 years.
    }
    \ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}

After 2nd parallel.

\end{document}
```

The result follows.

[image]

Comment: A list of related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286652/140133, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86366/140133, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164794/140133, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308260/140133.

Comment: It's fine @AdvanderVen. Did it work for you? The code is a little bit longer to better illustrate the behavior of parallel.
I would also advice to use `\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}` and the command `\enquote{Text}` if you use quotes from [differente languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark).

Comment: FHZ I ran your source text with Latex and it worked perfectly. However, I couldn't find the actual language texts. How does the source text look with the following two language texts?

German:

Besonders auffällig ist der frühere Eintritt der Reifungszeit und damit auch der Geschtechtsreife bei den Mädchen, die den Knaben um 1-2 Jahre vorauseilen. 

English:

Particularly noticeable is the earlier onset of the maturation period and thus also the maturity level of the girls, who are 1-2 years

Comment: Hi, try to change the contents in `\ParallelLText{ %\selectlanguage{brazil}` and in `\ParallelRText{ %  \selectlanguage{german}`. I would suggest to also remove lines with  the dummy text from `\lipsum[1-5]`.

Comment: Wouldn't you mind showing me the new, modified Latex source file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added a second example with `csquotes` and your texts in English and German. I let two `parallel` environments with the same sample texts.

Comment: I cannot say how grateful I am for your very knowledgeable and also very kind help. It is very special that you give this help without getting paid for it. Again thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I had to learn about it to start a project of a bilingual book to teach German. In this discussion I also learned about another package, `paracol`, which I will test soon. I ask you to up-vote any good question that helps you in TeX-SE and choose the best answer among them when it exists, this is the gesture of gratitude around here **AND**, _the most important_, help people in need when you can. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and thanks again.