# Is it possible to define even and odd page content separately?

Tags: page-numbering

Basically, the project I'm working on is a bilingual book, containing both text and music, with one language on even pages and the other language on odd pages. Since some of the music will span multiple pages, and there's a sort of pre-compiler that determines the layout of the music, I cannot *simply* use page breaks and alternate languages in the source file.

I do have a solution, but it's very ugly. It would essentially involve separate source files for the two languages, where I command the margins to print `2\thepage` and `2\thepage+1` in the two files, and then interleave them at the end.

Does anybody know of a LaTeX package or macro that would do this more elegantly?

In case it matters, I'm using `gregorio` and `lilypond-book` for the music, and `lualatex` for the final compilation.

Comment: You may be interested in [Syncing text on bilingual pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86366/17423).

Comment: The method with two documents is not ugly. You may automatize the interleaving of pages using `xr` package (to mark the pages to synchronize) and `pdfpages` package (to extract pages from each document).

Comment: I'd personally be interested in what kind of input syntax this would have with a hypothetical one-file document.