# Different texts on even and odd pages

Tags: eledmac, eledpar

I'm having issues with even and odd pages. Namely I want different languages to be on left and right pages.
Upon finding this answer: [Syncing text on bilingual pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86366/syncing-text-on-bilingual-pages) I've tried doing something similar, yet ultimately I keep on failing. I've got the context I want to go on odd pages in one tex file and on even in another. 
Namely the issue is that the file PICILeft.tex is now on the first few pages and PICIRight.tex after that. Not parallel with odd/even pages.

Here's the main tex file, can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
% !TEX program = LuaLaTeX+se
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[inner=0.65in, outer=0.35in, top=0.7in, bottom=0.6in, a4paper, head=12pt, headheight=30pt, headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar,metalogo,hyperref}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
 \fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}
 \fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

%DELI, POGLAVJA, ETC, ETC
\titleformat{\part}{\color{red}\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\color{red}}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\color{red}\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\color{red}}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\color{red}\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\color{red}}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{red}\normalfont\Large\bfseries\center}{\color{red}}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\color{red}\normalfont\large\bfseries\center}{\color{red}}{1em}{}

\newcommand{\black}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cent}[1]{\begin{center}{#1}\end{center}}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{}
\newcommand*{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\redit}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\it #1}}

\newcommand{\ginit}[3]{%
 \greannotation{\small \red{\textbf{#1}}}%
 \greannotation{\small \red{\textbf{#2}}}%
 \grecommentary{{\small \red{\emph{#3}}}}%
}

% INICIALKE
\input Acorn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}

\newcommand{\ginitnorm}{\renewcommand*\initfamily{\normalfont}}
\newcommand{\ginitgoth}{\renewcommand*\initfamily{\pgothfamily}}
\newcommand{\ginitsquare}{\renewcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}}

\grechangestyle{initial}{\initfamily\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\textcolor{red}\relax}
\newcommand{\redinit}{\grechangestyle{initial}{\initfamily\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\textcolor{red}\relax}}
\newcommand{\blackinit}{\grechangestyle{initial}{\initfamily\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\relax}}

\grechangestaffsize{19}

\title{\sc Hymnarium}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\include{PICILeft}
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\include{PICIRight}
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to latex and I wasn't really sure about what could interfere with what I'm trying to do here, so I figured I'd post the whole code, since it isn't all that much. Thanks for the guide. I shall read it asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I have not the content of your included file, so I can't tell you if it is ok.
2. You must use `\input` and not `\include` (as `\include` add new page).
3. You must use `\beginnumbering…\endnumbering` structure insided each side, and `\pstart…\pend` to delimite chunck of text
4. You should use reledmac/reledpar instead of eledmac/eledpar, which are deprecated.

Here a MWE for parallel typesetting http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples/3-reledpar_mwe.tex.